# list arguments in vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am switching from android studio to VScode for flutter development and, obviously, there are some shortcuts that on android studio different from those on VScode. One of those shortcuts that I could not find is the listing of all arguments of a widget. I am looking for a shortcut that lists all the args without entering any letter.

[image]

I used cmd + space and nothing happend. I also used shift + cmd + space and gave me something I am not looking for. So can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTRL + space works.

To check your keybinding, go to **Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**, and search for **Trigger Suggest**.

But also make sure you have the Flutter & Dart extension to get code hint/completion:
Dart: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code.
Flutter: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

Comment: it does not work for me, can you please check the shortcut name please?

Comment: @AliAlqallaf Answer updated to check shortcut settings.

Comment: thank you, it works now! it turns out that the shortcut was cmd + i

Answer (score 0):

Just CTRL + space works for me. I installed Intellij keymap as an extension on my VSCode too Here is an image of my vscode.
[Sugestions without type anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9xIk.png)

Comment: it does not work for me, can you please check the shortcut name please?

Answer (score 0):

For a given widget VS Code auto-completion provide both method and class, respectively purple and yellow symbols.

[image]

An option is to select the class of the widget you want to use instead of the method in the auto-completion list. Then, as soon as you will add the opening parenthesis, all arguments will be listed and available for selection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think that is the case for most people, unfortunately, it does not work for me